# Spending limit removed for this period but credit alert still active

Tags: azure

Good morning,

The management portal is showing me an orange alert which states that my credit will run out before my billing period. As soon as I saw the alert I went to the billing page and removed the spending limit for this period, however the management portal is still alerting me about the credit running out before time. Will the credit run out and my services stop even though I have removed the spending limit? or will it run out and continue billing me the extra dollars I need to make it through this period?

Thanks in advance

[image: Credit Alert]

Comment: I've noticed that the "credit alert" will remain orange even after the spending limit is removed.  Mine went down to 0 credit with 0 days.  However, looking at the bill summary showed the projected cost of the next bill incrementing each day.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that sometimes this change can take a while to be reflected in the portal even though it has been completed.  Are there any alerts indicating that it was not successful?

Comment: Sadly the only way I know to find out this is if my production sites go down, is there any other way to find this out?